# A simple looking yet tricky Second Order Nonlinear Differential Equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have been struggling with the following second order differential equation for quite a while,

$$y''(t)=\frac{(y'(t))^2}{y(t)}-\frac{(y'(0))^2}{y'(0)\times t+c}$$

Where $y'(0)$ is a constant of units $\frac{1}{[T]}$ and c is dimensionless. It looks fairly simple and I can bet there is a simple trick to be used to solve it but I just cannot see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If necessary, the initial conditions known are, $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)$ is approximately $8.7e43$.

My first reflex was to write $y''(t)$ as $\frac{dy'(t)}{dt}$ since I could potentially just integrate $\int\frac{(y'(0))^2}{y'(0)\times t+c}dt$, which is easy. However it didn't work.

Simiralry, I have tried separating $y''(t)$ into $\frac{dy'(t)}{dy(t)}\times y'(t)$. This however didn't work since isolating $y'(t)dy'$ was out of my range of skills.

Finally, I just tried to integrate both sides with respects to $t$, however, I lack information to compute $\int\frac{(y'(t)^2)}{y(t)}dt$ when using integration by parts.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried, what did not work, etc.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales done.

Comment: $c$ has to be dimensionless for this work, otherwise $y'(0)*t+c$ is adding two quantities of different dimensionalities.

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics yes yes I noticed the error after my second edit. thank you for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 3):

For the dimensions in the denominator on the right hand side to work out, $c$ actually must be dimensionless. So I will proceed according to that assumption. Furthermore, this implies that $y$ is dimensionless.

Let $y'(0) = K$

BIG EDIT: I don't think my previous answer to the question holds up to scrutiny. In particular, the step where I mainly went wrong was a derivative integral swap that I don't think was valid. Therefore, this is my updated solution:

Let us define a system of equations by introducing a new function $v(t)$, independent of $y$.

Observe that if $v(t) = y'(t)$ AND $v' = \frac{vy'}{y}-\frac{K}{t+\frac{c}{K}}$, then the original equation is true. So we define this as our system of differential equations. To solve this system:

$$v'+\frac{K}{t+\frac{c}{K}} = \frac{v}{y}\frac{dy}{dt} $$

$$\left(v'+\frac{K}{t+\frac{c}{K}}\right)dt = \frac{v}{y}dy $$

$$\int\left(v'+\frac{K}{t+\frac{c}{K}}\right)dt = \int\frac{v}{y}dy $$

Because v is not a function of y,

$$v+K\ln(t+\frac{c}{K}) = v\ln(y)+M $$

We can pin down $M$ using the initial conditions of the problem: $y(0) = 1$, $v(0) = K$, so

$$K+K\ln(\frac{c}{K}) = M $$

Subbing back in:

$$v+K\ln(t+\frac{c}{K}) = v\ln(y)+K+K\ln(\frac{c}{K}) $$

$$K\left(\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left(1+\ln\left(\frac{c}{K}\right)\right)\right) = v(\ln(y)-1)$$

$$K\frac{\left(\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left(1+\ln\left(\frac{c}{K}\right)\right)\right)}{\ln(y)-1} = v$$

Because I don't want to deal with it and it's a constant, let's define the constant $A = \left(1+\ln\left(\frac{c}{K}\right)\right)$

$$K\frac{\left(\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-A\right)}{\ln(y)-1} = v$$

Substituting this into $y'(t) = v(t)$

$$K\frac{\left(\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-A\right)}{\ln(y)-1} = \frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$K\left(\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-A\right)dt = (\ln(y)-1)dy$$

$$\int K\left(\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-A\right)dt = \int (\ln(y)-1)dy$$

$$ K\left(\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left((1+A)t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\right) = y(\ln(y)-2)+N$$

We know that $y(0)=1$, so to solve for N:

$$ K\left(\left(\frac{c}{K}\right)\ln\left(\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left(\frac{c}{K}\right)\right) = -2+N$$

$$ c\ln\left(\frac{c}{Ke}\right)+2 = N$$

So therefore,

$$ K\left(\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left((1+A)t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\right)-c\ln\left(\frac{c}{Ke}\right)+2 = y(\ln(y)-2)$$

If you REALLY want to isolate $y$, you need to use the Lambert W function.

$$ \left(K\left(\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left((1+A)t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\right)-c\ln\left(\frac{c}{Ke}\right)+2\right)\frac{1}{e^2} = \frac{y}{e^2}(\ln(\frac{y}{e^2}))$$

$$ W\left(\left(K\left(\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left((1+A)t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\right)-c\ln\left(\frac{c}{Ke}\right)+2\right)\frac{1}{e^2}\right) = \frac{y}{e^2}$$

$$ e^2 W\left(\left(K\left(\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\ln\left(t+\frac{c}{K}\right)-\left((1+A)t+\frac{c}{K}\right)\right)-c\ln\left(\frac{c}{Ke}\right)+2\right)\frac{1}{e^2}\right) = y$$

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you. C is indeed dimensionless I realized it after my second edit. Just rectified it now.

Comment: However I am confused by one part. At equations 15-16 you multiply by -1 to obtain yln(y) on the LHS. However only one sign changes on the RHS, is it an error or am I not seeing something?

Comment: And I belive that $\int(1-ln(y))dy=2*y-yln(y)$

Comment: You are right on both counts. Hold on.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for pointing those out.

Comment: Hey sorry for coming back so late, However I was arriving at the end of my problem when I realized that you might've maybe made an error? Because when I derive with respect of time equation 8, it doesn't equal equation 4. More mathematically, $(y'(1-ln(y)))'\neq(\frac{y'}{y})'y$, implying that $y'(1-ln(y))\neq\int(\frac{y'}{y})'y$

Comment: Pay close attention to how we’re integrating. We change the variable we integrate with in equation 7. It’s basically u substitution without the u.

Comment: Yes of course. But I was deriving with respect to time and It doesn't work, which might be the source of error. What would I have to derive $y'(1-ln(y))$ with respect to in order to verify your result? Since $\frac{d}{dt}(y'(1-ln(y)))$ Is not equal to $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{y'}{y})y$.

Comment: I find that equation 11 should be $\frac{dy}{dt}(1-ln(y))+\int ln(y)\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}dt = -Kln(Kt+c)+C$

Comment: I overhauled the answer because I think that the derivative integral swap I had in the first system may not have been valid. This should work now if you NEED an analytical solution. But for most things you might want to use this for, I'm pretty sure a numerical solution would suit you better.